# UIPageViewController with different ViewControllers

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, segue

I want to use UIPageViewController with tow button (next and preve) to display 7 View Controller with different content, this is my story board after implement UIPageViewController only .

My question is how I can put these view controllers inside UIPageViewController?

[image]
[image: page.xib]

Answer (score 2):

Answer in Swift:

Call the setViewControllers method to define your first VC, direction, etc. like this in your viewDidLoad of your UIPageVC instance:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dataSource = self
    let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "whatever storyboard id your first VC is")
    setViewControllers([vc],
                       direction: .forward,
                       animated: false,
                       completion: nil)
}
```

Use the UIPageViewControllerDataSource protocol methods to define what pages come before and after the current viewController as well as view controller count and index.

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                        viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
{
    // Return some VC based on what the current viewController param is.
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                        viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
{
   // Return some VC based on what the current viewController param is.
}

func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 7
}

func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return viewControllers!.index(of: viewControllers!.first!)!
}
```